# Unable to run command on Batch File

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments, windows-terminal

I have a batch file to open directories on Windows Terminal.

Currently there are 2 lines on my script:

```
cmd.exe /c wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "RAN" --title "Components" --tabColor "#8AD8FF" --colorScheme "One Half Dark" -d "C:\RAN\components-page"
```

And have a one for multiple panes:

```
cmd.exe /c wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "RAN" --title "Address" --tabColor "#9C37FF" --colorScheme "One Half Dark" -d "C:\RAN\address-page" ; split-pane -V -p "RAN" --title "Address Info" --tabColor "#9C37FF" -d "C:\RAN\address-info-page"
```

The thing is that it does work to open I get a page like this:

[What the command loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO4sj.png)

What I would like to do is simple to have that but in the same script make it start my pages, by doing by running the command `yarn start:local` in that directory, as currently I can only do it manually.

Is there a way to do this?

I have added at the end of the `-d (directory address)` a `&& yarn start:local.START` but hasn't work, no other online info I tried has work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you are using powershell in Windows Terminal, you can just add at the end: `powershell -NoExit "yarn start:local"`. So you're end command would be something like:

```
cmd.exe /c wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "RAN" --title "Components" --tabColor "#8AD8FF" --colorScheme "One Half Dark" -d "C:\RAN\components-page" powershell -NoExit yarn start:local
```

Comment: Sorry to add a new problem to this, but when done like this I loose the Tab Title, is there a way to keep the tab title?

Comment: I think you have to use --suppressApplicationTitle before the powershell command, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-advanced#suppress-title-changes